# Handling a large file upload with "io.Pipe" on the server side

Tags: google-app-engine, go, image-processing, image-uploading

As part of my learning process I recently started a new challenge to create a photomosaics  web app with golang. Since I am planning on hosting it on App Engine I divided it into 2 services: 1 to handle image uploads and the other to handle image processing. What I want to accomplish here is to start processing the image as soon as the first bytes are received. While doing my research I came across this gist [cryptix/client.go](https://gist.github.com/cryptix/9dd094008b6236f4fc57). I need to use this method to read the request into a io.Pipe and then stream it on the fly to my image processing service and none of my googling helped: all there is to see is a GO client sending files while I want a Go server receiving files.

**NOTE**:

- The two services are communicating via HTTP.
- I am using the REST pattern(No html form: Testing with POSTMAN).
- Concrete examples are most welcome.
- Please don't frown this is my first stackoverflow question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: «I need to use this method to read the request into a io.Pipe and then stream it on the fly to my image processing service»—so please go on and implement exactly this, as stated. What is your problem? Unfortunately, this really sounds like what is covered by [this classic essay](https://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat reluctant to answer this as i'm not sure what the exact problem is or what you have tried.

But this is just a streaming http read.

A http.Request actually holds the request body in a io.ReadCloser. This means that standard io.Reader implementations can stream this.

What you need to do is create a function that processes your data.

```
func process(r io.Reader) {
    // do something
}
```

then you can read it from the http handler

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    process(r.Body)
}
```

Without knowing your exact question or what you need help with I cannot elaborate further.